# Converting String to Int by map()

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I have an input (String): `"1 * 2 + 34 - 5"` and I want to split it into array and then convert "convertible" elements into integers. My code looks like this:

```
let arr: [Any] = readLine()!.split(separator: " ").map {Int($0) != nil ? Int($0) : $0}
```

Splitting is not a problem but I don't know why mapping doesn't work as it should. I get error:

```
error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '((AnySequence<String.Element>))'
note: overloads for 'Int' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Float), (Double), (Float80), (Int64), (Word), (NSNumber), (CGFloat)
```

I try to do the same in another way, with initializing new array:

```
let arr = readLine()!.split(separator: " ")
let newArray: [Any] = arr.map {Int($0) != nil ? Int($0) : $0}
```

but it also throws me an error:

```
error: 'map' produces '[T]', not the expected contextual result type '[Any]'
```

It is suprise for me that when I'm trying to do the same with for loop it works perfectly:

```
let arr = readLine()!.split(separator: " ")
var newArray = [Any]()
for x in arr
{
    if Int(x) != nil {newArray.append(Int(x)!)}
    else {newArray.append(x)}
}
print(newArray)
```

output: `[1, "*", 2, "+", 34, "-", 5]`

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? I mean if all 3 codes do the same thing so why only "for loop" works fine?

Comment: Swift 4.1 `let elements = fullString.components(separatedBy: " ").compactMap(Int.init)` or Swift 4 `let elements = fullString.components(separatedBy: " ").flatMap(Int.init)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify that the return type of your `map` block is `Any` rather than the type which is being inferred by the compiler (`Int`), e.g.

```
let fullString = "1 * 2 + 34 - 5"
let elements = fullString
    .components(separatedBy: " ")
    .map { Int($0) ?? $0 as Any}
```

Comment: `.map({Int($0) ?? $0 as Any})`

Comment: Good suggestion, @LeoDabus. I have edited my answer.